# Multiselect stacking up attribute value

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Good day, i have a multi select which has an attribute of number,
i need to get the total of selected options(number attribute) everytime i select a option, and minus its total when i cross out one,
ive tried

$("select[multiple='multiple']").unbind("change.multiple");

```
$("select[multiple='multiple']").bind("change.multiple", function(){
        debugger;
        var total = $("#b").text();
        var number = $(this).attr("number");
        $("#b").text(toal + number);
    });
```

but its not working
here is what ive already done
http://jsfiddle.net/5pkw2fq3/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
$("select").change(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
       sum += parseInt($( this ).attr('number'))  ;
    });
    $("#b").text(sum);
}).trigger("change");
```

### Working Demo

Comment: yeah, thanks buddy , i got it on this  
$( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
      sum += parseInt($( this ).attr('number'))  ;
    });
have a good day sir :)